# Create react app requires node 14 but I can't install node 14 on windows 7

Tags: node.js, create-react-app

I tried creating app using create react app but it says

> Create react app requires node 14

Now the problem is I have windows 7, and when I downloaded installer for node 14 -- it tells me it supports only windows 8 or higher.

What can I do? What are my options? Is there create react app compatible with node 13? I have node 13.

Comment: It's very difficult for the software development ecosystem to evolve and simultaneously remain backwards compatible on legacy platforms.

Comment: @selbie Maybe but what are my options? Granted I don't want to reinstall windows

Comment: You could try running Windows 10 in a VM. You could rent an AWS/Azure VM running Windows 10 and run remote desktop to connect to that.  You could buy a new PC.  Or just upgrade your OS to a newer version.  You could also install Linux side by side with your Windows 7 OS and do your development on that platform.  There's not a single scenario that involves node.exe working on Windows 7.